# Why do I have to drop into Google to see the names of connections?

Tags: contacts, linkedin

I have a Business Plus account on LinkedIn.  If I search for a name and they are outside of my immediate circle, all I get is "LinkedIn Member" instead of the person's name. I get that they want me to upgrade to the Super Snazzy™ account to see everyone's information, but what is strange is that if I then pop open Google, and search by the person's title, their name comes right up in the Google search.

Is there a setting I need to change in LinkedIn to get this information directly, or am I stuck with this end-around approach?